# How to sum Time from a DataGridView Columns

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime, datagridview

I have a DataGrid with a time column that I need to sum to get the total time, but I can't get that!
I'm using this code to try the time sum, with Linq:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    textBox8.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                 .AsEnumerable()
                                 .Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.Cells["Duracao"].Value.ToString()))
                                 .ToString();
}
```

Can anybody help me here?
Regards

Comment: What is your format of your DateTime in that cell ?

Comment: Depending on the format of your "Duracao" strings, using [`TimeSpan.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx) and adding things as a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might work better.

Comment: You repeatedly sum the values of the cell over and over again without being needed.

Comment: @Pankaj, I save it to the DB as varchar(50), and I display it like "00:00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at below code sample. May be it will help you :

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    // Bind Grid
    var times = new List<Info>();
    times.Add(new Info(){ Time = "0:3:5" });
    times.Add(new Info() { Time = "0:2:10" });
    times.Add(new Info() { Time = "1:15:30" });
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = times;

    // Retrieve total seconds
    double seconds = 0;
        seconds = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Sum(x => TimeSpan.Parse((x.Cells["Time"].Value.ToString())).TotalSeconds);

    // Assign to textbox
    textBox8.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).Hours + ":" + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).Minutes
            + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).Seconds;
}
```

**Info Class:**

```
public class Info
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You did not add: `this.dataGridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: there is no need to add it in datagrid.

Comment: @SpiderCode thank you! It's working now :D I'll only need to work in the display type now, i need with this layout "00:00" and it retrieves me "0:0"! A big thank you :D regards