# How can I convert this SQL code into LINQ format?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sum

This is my SQL table

```
CREATE TABLE PlayerXP 
(
    id_partida INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ganhoxp    NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    duracao    VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
)
```

This code to the linq format

```
SELECT
    SUM (60 * CONVERT(int, LEFT( duracao, 2)) +
         CONVERT(int, RIGHT(duracao, 2))) AS TotalSegundos
FROM PlayerXP;
```

The column `duracao` is formatted as Minute/Seconds (`mm:ss`)

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: I am a beginner in programming and I am still learning Linq, so it is difficult to have the basis to write my own code, learning alone, SQL already has some domain. But I will definitely look more at the documentation

Comment: With a little more research I discovered another method (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013073/how-to-sum-time-from-a-datagridview-columns) that also worked, from my DataGridView, which was taking this data from the db and showing it on the Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the table were a business entity:

```
public class PlayerXP 
{
 public int id_partida;
 public string ganhoxp;
 public string duracao;
}
```

with an object

```
PlayerXP playerxp = new PlayerXP()
```

and if the value of `duracao` in an object of that business entity class were

```
playerxp.duracao = "12:60"
```

then,
Try this:

```
int TotalSegundos = (playerxp.duracao.Split(":")
                              .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                              .First() * 60) + playerxp.duracao.Split(":")
                                                      .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                                                      .Last();
```

the `TotalSegundos` value i got is `780`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I tested it and it worked.

Comment: Okay mate, no issues